# Choosing one of two files to include in PHP

Tags: php, file, insert

I do apologize for asking this stupid question but I am wondering if you can help me..

i want insert among file $cat1 or $cat2 to in page.php...
the code i was create e.g.

```
<? //config.php
$cat_all = ($cat2 or $cat1);
$cat1 = "cat.php" ;
$cat2 = "../back-up/cat.php"; //default anyway
if(file_exists($cat1)){
    require_once $cat1;
}else{
    require_once $cat2;
}
?>

<? //page.php
require "config.php";
function ShowIndexProd($number){
    $ar = file($cat_all); // <------- input here //
    $sizear = count($ar)-$number;
    $data = explode("#",$ar[$sizear]);
    echo "
    <td class='BoxIndex' width='30%'><a href='prod_show.php?id=$sizear'><IMG SRC='img/$data[5]' width=150 border=0></a> <BR /><BR />
        <B><FONT COLOR='red'> $deti[2] </FONT></B> <BR />
        <B>Price:</B>$rp $data[3] $usd<BR />
        <a href='prodshow.php?id=$sizear'><b><FONT COLOR='#FF6600'> more details... </FONT></b></a>
    </td>";
}
```

but the result: file $cat1 or $cat2 printed to html page, that i want them as file configuration..
any help would much appreciate and thank you

Comment: Belongs on StackOverflow: http://www.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: We're going to need to see this cat.php.

Comment: OK, Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, thank for your advance, but the cat.php it self really simple, like:

Properties
Cars
Animals
ETC

Comment: 1) Use the full PHP tag, i.e. `<?php //Code in here ?>` instead of `<? //code ?>` 2) Give us `cat.php`, if `cat.php` is not PHP code, it will echo it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `<? ?>` tags in files @cat1 and @cat2.

Comment: what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: sorry - I didn't notice that actual tags were removed ;)

Comment: you'r right Michal Dymel, in @cat1 and @cat2 no tag <? ?>
because it as category and before their name like cat.txt, i changed it to make more secure...
thank you

Comment: but the impact after put tag <? ?> it shown in my category... any idea bos? would be great thank you..

Comment: I think we won't be able to help you without you pasting content of these files...

Answer (score 0):

When you include or require a file it needs to have the PHP tags if you want to run PHP in the included file. I see you are using `<?` (known as short tags) so that needs to be in the file where the code needs to run.

You might, on a side note, consider moving to long tags `<?php` as this is more portable but that is a minor consideration at this stage.

Now once you have included `cat.php` it is going to run there and then. So any output will be above your current scripts output. If that is the expected behaviour then good. If it is not then you might want to think about where the output is wanted and include there.

I am not sure what you are trying to do with `$cat_all = ($cat2 or $cat1);` as you appear not to have defined the contents of those values until the next few lines. Also you do not appear to be using `$cat_all` anywhere after you define it.

If the result of including the files is not as you had imagined it would be that is a second issue and I would recommend posting another question with the contents of one or both cat.php files as well as the one above. Remember to tell us the expected and actual results so we can see where things are going wrong for you.

I suspect given the nature of your question and the fact that you fell for a beginners mistake that there might be other questions you will need to ask as you learn more about PHP. Even if we don't admit it we were all once beginners too.

Answer (score -1):

Try [`include`](http://php.net/include)`'config.php'` ?

Comment: Thank my friend for your nice consideration, but unfortunately i didn't see any change

Comment: "i want insert among file $cat1 or $cat2 to in page.php" can you try to clarify this - it makes pretty much zero sense to me at least.